# Handling error from Async Task in an Async ASP.Net page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous

I have an async ASP.Net page (Async="true") with code as below.

If an error occurs within the async task method 'DoTask1', then it seems that its not handled by the ASP.Net page framework like other normal errors.

I tried getting Server.GetLastError() in EndAsyncOperation1 method, but it returns a null even when an error occurred in DoTask1 method. **Is there some special way to handle errors that occur in an async task?**

```
    protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
              PageAsyncTask pagetask1 = new PageAsyncTask(new BeginEventHandler(BeginAsyncOperation1),
                    new EndEventHandler(EndAsyncOperation1),
                    new EndEventHandler(TimeoutAsyncOperation1),
                    new object[] { employeeId, totalEarnings }, true);
                RegisterAsyncTask(pagetask1);
    }

    //Async Task method below is called by the registered task
    private void DoTask1(object[] paras)
    {
            //line below throws an exception on the async task thread
            string x = null;
            string y = x.Trim();
           //More code come here
     }

   IAsyncResult BeginAsyncOperation1(object sender, EventArgs e, AsyncCallback cb, object state)
    {
        task1 = new AsyncTaskDelegate(DoTask1);
        IAsyncResult result = task1.BeginInvoke(state as object[], cb, "task1");
        return result;
    }

   void EndAsyncOperation1(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        task1.EndInvoke(ar);
        if (success1 == null)
        {
            success1 = true;
        }
    }

    void TimeoutAsyncOperation1(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        success1 = false;
    }
```

Comment: Errm, please read the code in your **DoTask1** method. It's just two lines. Shouldn't be too hard to understand what is going on there -- or do you do this deliberately to test the error handling, perhaps?

Comment: I added those 2 lines deliberately to see how I can handle an error on the async task. I need to know how to handle error in such a case since Server.GetLastError returns null in EndAsyncOperation1 method.

Comment: I see, i started to wonder and question myself :-D

Comment: Using BeginInvoke on delegates is almost always a mistake. Not sure you understand what this does. It posts the work to the thread-pool which is not useful in ASP.NET.

Comment: Actually, if you see Async pages docs in ASP.Net, it says that it doesn't go to the thread pool but instead gets a I/O thread to execute the async task that is not from the ASP.Net thread pool. This is the beauty/advantage of using Async page in ASP.Net. You can see more at this link: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/10/12/427318.aspx

Comment: What thread executes your code does not matter. One thread is blocked. No benefit, but overhead instead. Async IO, though, does not use threads at all. That's where the benefit is.

Comment: NO. MAIN THREAD is  NOT BLOCKED and that is the beauty of Async page in ASP.Net. Please read Async pages in ASP.Net in detail and try to run some sample code in Visual Studio debugger, so you can see for yourself that when async task executes the original page thread is not blocked. As an example, if original page thread had an id of id1, the async task thread had an id of id2 and then when returning to original page you will find that thread id is not id1 but something different.

Comment: I never said the request thread was blocked. It is not. But a thread-pool thread will be in use instead. The same amount of threads is in use in both models, just with more overhead now. Accomplishes nothing (or tell me what it does accomplish).

Comment: Async page is a special designed feature in ASP.Net by Microsoft. Its not just multi-threading as often people think it to be, but it is a multi-threading framework that is meant to fit in perfectly with the ASP.Net frameowork. It makes sure that the ASP.Net thread-pool thread does not get blocked when page executes for long duration.

Comment: In my case, I reduced a 10 seconds call of multiple database updates to about 2 to 3 seconds after using this. You did say 'One thread is blocked', if you look in your comments. Also, the ASP.Net thread pool thread is returned to the thread pool when async method starts on a worker thread, which is the chief benefit here. then when async method ends, a thread from ASP.Net thread pool is used to continue page processing. So what we accomplish, is that the ASP.Net threadpool thread is not blocked waiting for a long async operation to complete.

Comment: Benefits - ASP.Net app can become more scalabale when time-consuming methods are being executed in code-behind and in some cases we end up with faster page response times as it happened in my case.

Comment: @usr, Please look at this link also, which explains it more better: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163725.aspx

Comment: Async pages are about making IO work non-blocking. The examples on that page are starting IO. Nowhere do they use Delegate.BeginInvoke. CPU cannot benefit from this. You should probably try to understand how async IO works to see why this is different.

Comment: Look at this link to see how they use BeginInvoke for Async ASP.Net page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.pageasynctask.aspx

Comment: They try to showcase some timeout feature there. The example is bogus otherwise.

Comment: @usr, You are right about that. The net effect could be a more scalable web app. Like I said, it helped increase performance also in my case. Also, from MSDN: "Scalability increases because thread-pool threads are used more efficiently. Threads that would otherwise be stuck waiting for I/O to complete can now be used to service other requests. "

Comment: @usr, All I wanted to know was how to handle errors in my case. I wasn't really wanting to discuss what is Async page and what are its benefits. My question in bold clearly states this. I am not interested in timeout since that is not  a part of my question.

Comment: Just informing you that you might have a misunderstanding here. If you app got faster this way you probably introduced concurrency. Now you might have a race condition.

Comment: @usr, There is no race condition in my case. In async ASP.Net page, there is a feature that says whether you want to run multiple page tasks in parallel or serially. I am running them in parallel since each task is completely independent of each other in my code, and that is why I get the performance benefit. Also, I end up using I/O thread and not a thread from ASP.Net threadpool for my async tasks.

Comment: Even if you were using an IO thread, which normal thread-pool items do not use (and you seem to refuse the notion that BeginInvoke just posts to the thread-pool) doing that would not help you in any way. That said, if you use threading for concurrency that is a valid use case. You might want to investigate more modern styles of doing that like using TPL or async/await.

Comment: @user, You are right, a thread pool thread is being used for the async task. I just checked.

Comment: @usr, But it did increase the response time. Also, it seems to truly not use thread pool threads for async method I would have to use methods like: HttpWebRequest.BeginGetResponse and SqlCommand.BeginExecuteReader. Thanks for all the input you gave as it has revealed something important to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the answer to my problem.

One can follow 2 approaches when handling async task error in an ASP.Net page that is flagged with Async = "true". Please note that asyn task method that is called by code in this question is 'DoTask1'.

- **APPROACH 1:** Do not enclose anything in try catch, even the code that executes as an async task, as the default ASP.Net error handling will come into play in ASP.Net. So, if your page was posting back as an ajax postback, then the ScriptManager's AsynError event will fire and you can do whatever you like in this event, or if its non-ajax postback then use Page_Error event at the page level to handle the error.  Sample code is as given below.

  **In my case Server.GetLastError was returning a null since I was clearing the error (i.e. Server.ClearError) in ScriptManager's AsyncError event.**

  ```
   protected void radScriptManager_AsyncPostBackError(object sender, 
                                       System.Web.UI.AsyncPostBackErrorEventArgs e)
  {
      //log the exception using ELMAH or any other logging mechanism
      Exception ex = Server.GetLastError() ;
      if (ex != null)
      {
          Exception bex = ex.GetBaseException();
          if (bex != null)
          {
              Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(bex);
          }
      }
      Server.ClearError();
  }
  ```
- **APPROACH 2:** The second approach involves putting the call to EndInvoke method in EndAsyncOperation1 within a try catch. **The beauty of EndInvoke method is that it re-throws the exception that occurred on the async task method** ( i.e. 'DoTask1'), so we can catch it and handle it as shown in code below. I have used ELMAH to log and handle error in this case, but you could use any logging mechanism.

  There is no need to put the code in the async task method within a try catch when using this second approach, since if an error occurs in async method then it will automatically propagate to the EndInvoke method.

  ```
     void EndAsyncOperation1(IAsyncResult ar)
  {
      try
      {
          task1.EndInvoke(ar);
          success1 = true;

      }
      catch (Exception e1)
      {
          success1 = false;
          //log the exception (this will log error and also send out an error email)
          Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(e1);
      }
      if (success1 == null)
      {
          success1 = true;
      }
  }
  ```